# Cache management system in magento

Tags: cache, ce-1.8.1.0

Magento cache is used to speed up performance. The cached files is stored in `var/cache`.

My doubt is how cached files are retrieved and shown in frontend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nick Jones described how the cache works](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/)

`Mage::app()->getCache()` gives you a Zend_Cache instance, where you can do a lot of things:

```
save($value, $key, $tags = array(), $lifeTime=null)
load($key)
remove($key)
clean($tags = array()
```

Magento does different things:

## Configuration, Layouts

It stores the parsed XML configuration and layout to avoid parsing the XML files again

## Blocks HTML output

It stores the output of a block to avoid getting data and rendering HTML again (if configured so)

## Translations

It parses the CSV files (and sort it through the different layers: Module translation, locale.csv) with the translation and stores it in cache to not parse it again

## Collections Data

Magento can store collection data in cache, but afaik is this used nowhere...

## EAV types and attributes

It retrieves the EAV attributes and does something with it, don't ask me wh
at.

## Web Services Configuration

The same as configuration: Parsing and merging xml files

## EE: Page Cache

It stores the whole page output in cache to avoid rendering the complete HTML again

I hope this answers your question.